# Establecer fecha mayor-menor a Input Date en Laravel

Tags: laravel, date, validación, input

no puedo hacer el título de esta pregunta más largo. Así que explicaré bien en que consiste el tema.

Estoy trabajando en Laravel 9.3, con el paquete Laravel Breeze y Sanctum. Estoy desarrollando un sitio de registro de consultas médicas para un proyecto de estudio en universidad. Y tengo una duda porque la verdad no sé cómo hacerlo, solo pido sugerencias. No pondré mucho código ya que no tengo errores, más que nada solo es validación lo que me gustaría hacer.

Estoy desarrollando un formulario de registro de médicos y hay unos datos que pido al usuario ingresar, es su horario y días de trabajo durante un periodo. Pido que seleccione 2 fechas para el periodo, la fecha la cual comienza y la fecha de finalización, luego pido su horario de ingreso y término.

La validación que busco es que, al seleccionar la fecha de finalización del periodo, ésta no sea menor que la fecha de inicio.

Como dice el titulo establecer el valor al input que depende del primero sería una forma de validación, ya que el input ya tendría un valor definido. Un ejemplo sería lo siguiente, a modo de una idea solamente.

```
<input id="FechaMinima" type="date" min="1980-12-31" required/>
```

Ese input *fecha* ya no se puede establecer una fecha menor a la establecida.

Explico de la siguiente forma:

```
Fecha Inicio| Fecha Fin
01-03-2022  | 30-12-2022
```

El usuario no puede en seleccionar una fecha menor a 01-03-2022.
Luego ocurre lo mismo para el horario.

```
Horario Inicio | Horario Fin
08:00 AM       | 16:00 PM
```

El usuario si ya escribió 08:00 AM luego el horario de termino no puede ser menor que 08:00 AM.

Espero me puedan aconsejar, darme alguna sugerencia si pueden poner código también estaría agradecido. A mí se me ocurren varias formas de hacerlo desde usar JavaScript para que tome el valor mientras se escribe o selecciona y luego pasarlo al input que depende del primero. Hasta usar Laravel mismo para la validación, quizás creando alguna regla personalizada.

He estado leyendo la siguiente documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation
Para informarme, pero aún me considero un novato en Laravel y hay muchas cosas que no entiendo aún.

Lo siguiente es el código de la vista que tengo el formulario que estoy desarrollando.

```html
<x-app-layout>
  <form method="POST" action="{{route('store-profesional') }}">
    <div class="mt-4">
      <x-input-label for="CajaNombre" :value="__('Nombre')" style="font-size: 14px;"/>
      <x-text-input id="CajaNombre" class="block mt-1 w-25" type="text" minlength="4" maxlength="30" name="CajaNombre" required autofocus />
      <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('CajaNombre')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <div class="mt-4">
      <x-input-label for="CajApellidos" :value="__('Apellidos')" style="font-size: 14px;"/>
      <x-text-input id="CajApellidos" class="block mt-1 w-25" minlength="4" maxlength="30" type="text" name="CajApellidos"></x-text-input>
      <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('CajApellidos')" class="mt-2"/>
    </div>

    <div class="mt-4">
      <x-input-label for="CajaRUT" :value="__('RUT')" style="font-size: 14px;"/>
      <x-text-input id="CajaRUT" placeholder="Ingrese un RUT" name="CajaRUT" class="block mt-1 w-25" type="text" title="Ej: 11111111-1" minlength="9" maxlength="10" required/>

    </div>
 
    <div class="mt-4">
      <x-input-label for="CajaFecha" :value="__('Fecha de Nacimiento')" style="font-size: 14px;" />
      <x-text-input id="CajaFecha" name="CajaFecha" min="1972-01-01" max="2004-12-31" class="block mt-2 w-25" type="date" required/>
    </div>
                        
    <div class="mt-4">
      <x-input-label for="CajaEspecialidad" :value="__('Especialidad')" style="font-size: 14px;"/>
      <x-text-input id="CajaEspecialidad" name="CajaEspecialidad" type="text" class="block mt-1 w-50" title="Indique su especialidad (si tiene), o la profesion que estudió" minlength="10" maxlength="50" required/>
    </div>
  
    <!-- FECHA DE INICIO PERIODO -->
    <div class="mt-4">
      <x-input-label for="DateInicio" :value="__('Periodo de Inicio')" style="font-size: 14px;"/>
      <x-text-input id="DateInicio" name="DateInicio" type="date" class="block mt-1" required/>
    </div>

    <!-- INPUT QUE DEPENDE DE LA FECHA DE INICIO -->
    <div class="mt-4">
      <x-input-label for="DateFin" :value="__('Periodo Fin')" style="font-size: 14px;"/>
      <x-text-input id="DateFin" name="DateFin" type="date" class="block mt-1" required/>
    </div>

    <!-- HORA DE INICIO LABORAL -->
    <div class="mt-4">
      <x-input-label for="HoraInicio" :value="__('Horario de Inicio')" style="font-size: 14px;"/>
      <x-text-input id="HoraInicio" name="HoraInicio" type="time" class="block mt-1 w-25" required/>
    </div>

    <!-- HORA FIN QUE DEPENDE DE HORA INICIO -->
    <div class="mt-4">
      <x-input-label for="HoraFin" :value="__('Horario Término')" style="font-size: 14px;"/>
      <x-text-input id="HoraFin" name="HoraFin" type="time" class="block mt-1 w-25" required/>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" class="btn btn-outline-primary" />
  </form>
</x-app-layout>
```

*Nota: No intenten ejecutar este código no creo les funcione si no está bajo ambiente Laravel, lo puse como Snippet para que se vea ordenado.*

Finalmente, de esto es el tema es una pregunta más que una ayuda con algún error de código.
Espero recibir sugerencias.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu archivo Request puedes agregar estas reglas de validación para cada campo respectivo:

```
'DateInicio' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|before:DateFin',
'DateFin' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after:DateInicio|before_or_equal:'.date('Y-m-d'),
'HoraInicio' => 'required|date_format:H:i|before:HoraFin',
'HoraFin' => 'required|date_format:H:i|after:HoraInicio',
```

Te explico un poco las reglas de validación para que las puedas editar a tu gusto:

`date_format` valida el formato con el que deben enviar tu fecha y hora, puedes editarlo al que necesites.

`before` valida que la fecha u hora sea anterior a la que indiques, puedes pasarle el nombre de otro campo y tomara esa fecha para validar la fecha u hora máxima.

`after` valida que la fecha u hora sea posterior a la que indiques, al igual que la anterior puedes pasarle otro campo que hayas mandado en el formulario.

`before_or_equal` valida que la fecha u hora sea anterior o igual a la que le indiques, así mismo le puedes pasar un valor de otro campo.